# Пример подключения к БД в Денвере

Tags: denwer, php

Пример подключения к БД в Денвере. Есть у кого-нибудь, уважаемые мастера?

Что в ниже приведенном коде изменить? Или что изменить в файлах?

```
session_start();
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
//ob_implicit_flush();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
define('CA', true);
require_once "config/db.conf.php";
require_once "config/conf.php";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите файл conf.php

```
<?
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "BDDD";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpasswd = "";

$baza=false;

function dbConnect()
{
    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname, $baza;
    if (!$baza) {
        //mysql_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd ) or die( "Ошибка подключения к БД" );
mysql_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd ) or die( mysql_error() );
        mysql_select_db( $dbname );
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
        $baza=true;
    }
}

dbConnect();
?>
```

Comment: Еще лучше сразу научиться пользоваться классами, которые работают с БД...

Comment: Научи......

Answer (score 0):

Настройки базы данных наверняка кроются в этом файле config/db.conf.php Нужно смотреть его и менять данные доступа к БД в нем.

Comment: Вроде все нашел, но выводит всякие ошибки при подключении к БД. У кого-нибудь есть пример - готовый php файл с подключением к БД Денвер?

Answer (score 0):

А нет разницы, на денвер подключается скрипт или нет. База MySQL и этим все сказано. Смотрите файлы изнутри вот эти

```
require_once "config/db.conf.php";
require_once "config/conf.php";
```